# How to ensure no duplicates created in DB on connection loss

Tags: java, android, api, http, backend

Евгений Кравцов:
I develop some tiny service with http backend and android app. And recently i felt the lack of knowledge in such a systems.

Case: 
 - Client makes order in app and send request to server
 - Server successfuly recieved data and make a database row for order
 - After database work completes, backend tries to respond to App with 200 success code.
 - App user faced some internet connection problems and can not receive server response. App gets timeout exception and notify user, that order was not successful
 - After some time, internet connection on user device restored and he send another request with same oreder.
 - Backend recieves this again and create duplicate for previous order

So i got 2 orders in database, but user wanted to create only one.

Question: How can i prevent such a behavior?

Comment: how would you define whether it is duplicate order/request ? it might be new request/order.

Comment: Yeah) This is another side of a problem. It coulld be different order, and generally it is, but sometimes its not.

Comment: then, there is no way.. you need to identify somehow, if it is identical order, then only it can be prevented otherwise it is not possible, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a key to your table in the db, for example defining the key as compound key of `user_id, type` -  so specific user cannot make 2 orders with the same order type.

This will cause the second db insert to fail.

Comment: Or you can just let user see all his orders. Not letting do more than one request per few minutes will also probably help))))